# how to get extension file NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I want get extension (format file from NSString) but I dont know about it please tell me syntax for getting format file from NSString.

```
NSString *name = @"Xcode-tutorial.pdf"
```

I want get .pdf format and store in one variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this my dear:

```
NSString *a = [name pathExtension];
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [`NSString`s `pathExtension` method](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1407801-pathextension):

```
NSString *fileExtension = [name pathExtension];
```

Answer (score 4):

Did you look in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/pathExtension)? There is a method that does just that:

```
NSString *ext = [name pathExtension];
NSLog(@"%@", ext);
```